# When does Angular re-render DOM in loops?

Tags: angular, ngfor

Reading about how to prevent extra re-rendering using `trackBy` I remembered that when `*ngFor` gets new array reference it re-renders all its elements, and `trackBy` solves this problem. Today I've encountered this example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: `<div *ngFor="let todo of todos">
                  {{todo.title}}
                </div>`
})
export class Test2Component {
  @Input() todos: any;
}
```

`app-test` is used in root component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: `<button (click)="add()">Add</button>
                <app-test [todos]="todos"></app-test>`
})
export class Test2Component {
  todos = [{ title: 'One' }, { title: 'Two' }];

  add() {
    this.todos = [...this.todos, { title: 'Three' }];
  }
}
```

When I press the button, new array is created and passed into `app-test`, so `*ngFor` should re-render all the items but it only adds new item instead, as were seen in DevTools. It's cool but now I'm confused about how actually Angular does full `*ngFor` re-rendering, don't I see obvious details?

Comment: How are you determining that angular is NOT rerendering the whole list?

Comment: In DevTools you can see changed elements are being highlighted. In my case only new elements which were added have this highlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default trackBy function tracks items by identity:

```
const trackByIdentity = (index: number, item: any) => item
```

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/be21eaa618ad156c83ba9821590ae99093a33ec5/packages/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_iterable_differ.ts#L27).

When you use the spread operator, you only do a shallow copy. This means the item reference is still the same in the new array.

So the framework knows it's the same object at the same index and I won't change the dom if the rendered element is the same as the one already present.

`trackBy` is usefull when the reference changes (new object) but you still have the same value. For example when relying on immutability, you are creating a new object because you changed another field.

Comment: Yes but if there are no changes in all items except the new one, completely new object must replace them all anyway? I've noticed that it's happening when I'm not using destructuring like in my example and just setting brand new array. With destructuring it's only new item getting highlighted in DevTools, `ngFor` behaves like it has `trackBy` applied on it in that case.